# showing wrong password or username even though it is correct password or username

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mysqli

I'm creating login form using AJAX, i,m trying to make it work from 4 days but unable to do so
 in this i have few issues i.e., if i enter Valid username & password also then also its not getting logged in to the page, i don know where im going wrong please 
 can any one find it out where im going wrong, it would be really very help full.

login.php

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 
    $mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax1");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>

    <head>
        <title> login script with ajax</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:#b3ffff">

        <div style="padding-left:500px ; padding-top:200px">

            Username:   <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br><br>
            Password:   <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
                        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="button" value="Log In">
                        <p style="color:black">Havent Registered? <a href="index.php">Register</a>.</p><br><br>
                        <div id="display" style="color:red"></div>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#submit").click(function(){
                        var password = $("#username").val();
                        var password = $("#password").val();

                        var datastring = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password;

                        if(username=='' || password==''){
                            $("#display").html("Please Enter All The Fields");
                        }
                        else{
                            $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "success.php",
                            data: datastring,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(result){
                                    $("#display").html(result);
                                    window.location = "welcome.php";
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

success.php

```
<?php

        $mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax1");
        session_start();

        if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
            header('location:welcome.php');
        }

        $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['username']);
        $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password']); 

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername' AND password='$hashed_password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $hashed_password=$row['password'];

        if(password_verify($mypassword, $hashed_password)) {
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
            //$_SESSION['id']=$row['userid'];
            echo'Successfully Registered';
        exit();
        }    
        else 
        {
        echo'Invalid username or password';
        }
?>
```

welcome.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        header('location:login.php');
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <div style="Padding-left:200px; padding-top:100px">
            <?php
                $mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax1");
                $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from `users` where userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
                $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                echo 'Welcome - '.$row['username'];
            ?>

            <!--br><br>
                <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
            <br><br-->

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add password_verify function code here

Comment: To format use **4 leading spaces** and not tabs or more spaces

Comment: Also if you want to redirect only when username and password are correct, do `if (result.indexOf("Welcome") !=-1)  window.location = "welcome.php"` since the success is also executed if the PHP returns error. Also you cannot redirect using Ajax, so the `header('location:login.php');` will be ignored by the Ajax

Comment: Remove password where clause from query because user entered value doesn't match with hased one so just fetch the password using username where clause and use password_verify function

Comment: Please make sure that you are accepting answers for the people that are helping you. Several people have tried to help you and you just re-post the question after you get what you want and then ask another question. You need to give credit to the people that are helping you.

Comment: sir now its accepting the username and password  but when i give wrong password or username then also its accepting the value so should i write another write code in jquery that when username or password is incorrec it should show incorrect username or password?

Comment: when the user entre proper username and password na then it will redirect to welcome.php right ? so how to redirect to that welcome.php without reloading the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your submit function on your login.php you have set the your variables wrong.  Change them to this:

```
var username = $("#username").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
```

After you do that, do what v Sugumar suggested in his answer.

Comment: sir now its accepting the username and password  but when i give wrong password or username then also its accepting the value so should i write another write code in jquery that when username or password is incorrec it should show incorrect username or password?

Comment: when the user entre proper username and password na then it will redirect to welcome.php right ? so how to redirect to that welcome.php without reloading the page?

Comment: @keerthi patil If you have researched how to redirect your page and still have not figured out an answer to your last comment, please post a new question to get additional help.

Answer (score 2):

remove  `AND password='$hashed_password'`

from

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername' AND password='$hashed_password'";
```

just check whether the username exists

using

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername'";
```

and then check the password using `password_verify()`

change your

```
password_verify(){
     echo 'success';
}else{
  echo 'error';
}
```

and in ajax

```
success:function(data){
   if(data.trim() == 'success'){
       window.location.href='success.php'
    }else if(data.trim()== 'error'){
       ///use some javascript to display the error message
    }
}
```

Comment: sir now its accepting the username and password  but when i give wrong password or username then also its accepting the value so should i write another write code in jquery that when username or password is incorrec it should show incorrect username or password?

Comment: if it is wrong then it show Invalid username or password as in the else statement of password_verify

Comment: ok sir i got ur point, but as far i know when the users get logged in na then it will redirect to the welcome.php page ok, so my question is it should redirect to the page without loading the page right ?

Comment: echo something like 'done' and success for 'error' for failure in password_verify. if it returns success then redirect else stay in the same page and display something is wrong.... sorry I dont understand your question

Comment: actually my question is when the user entre proper username and password na then it will redirect to welcome.php right ?  so how to redirect to that welcome.php without reloading the page?

Answer (score 1):

You have defined password twice instead of Username.

```
var password = $("#username").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
```

Correct this and check your code again.

Comment: when the user entre proper username and password na then it will redirect to welcome.php right ? so how to redirect to that welcome.php without reloading the page?